# How to display dataset in Horizontal bar in the Excel?

Tags: excel, office365

I have over 100 cities in a spreadsheet with monthly sales count data in a spreadsheet as shown in the picture.

I am trying to display the data in a Horizontal bar by having city name on the y-axis and months in the x-axis.

How to set the horizontal bar diagram in the excel? (office 365)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select the Insert tab in the toolbar at the top of the screen. Click on the Bar Chart button Microsoft Excel in the Charts group and then select a chart from the drop down menu. In this example, we have selected the first bar chart (called Clustered Bar) in the 2-D Column section.

Comment: @Riddhi..thank you. .. I followed the same steps before approaching for help.. I think.. i will have to populate the data .. which i am not sure, how to do that..